# Sum the elapsed time between timestamps SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sum, subquery, aggregate

I have a query that returns me the number of seconds between timestamps for events happening on a given machine's production run.

I want to get the total amount of time grouped by the statusCode of the machine during that duration.  Ex. Running, Unplanned downtime, planned downtime.

I think this involves a aggregate of an aggregate which i know is not allowed. I am sure there is a way to do this though

```
SELECT
    p1.productionRunId,
    p1.statusCodeId,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, MAX(p2.startTime), p1.startTime) AS seconds
FROM
    productionLog p1
INNER JOIN 
    wincc.dbo.productionLog p2 ON p1.productionRunId = p2.productionRunId
                               AND p2.startTime < p1.startTime
GROUP BY
    p1.startTime, p1.productionRunId, p1.statusCodeId
```

[Here is a picture of my current results with a description of what I would like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5xM6.png)

Comment: remove `p.startTime` from `group by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost had it.  You can use the SELECT query above as a sub-query of another query to handle summing the time periods.  See whether this does what you are looking for:

```
declare @p table (startTime datetime, productionRunId int, statusCodeId int)

insert @p values
('1/1/2016 15:43:00', 1, 1),
('1/1/2016 15:43:05', 1, 1),
('1/1/2016 15:43:01', 2, 2),
('1/1/2016 15:43:09', 2, 2),
('1/1/2016 15:44:02', 2, 2),
('1/1/2016 15:44:09', 2, 2),
('1/1/2016 15:44:31', 3, 1),
('1/1/2016 15:44:45', 3, 1)

SELECT
    productionRunId,
    statusCodeId,
    SUM(seconds) AS totalSeconds
FROM (
    SELECT
        p1.productionRunId,
        p1.statusCodeId,
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, MAX(p2.startTime), p1.startTime) AS seconds
    FROM @p p1
    INNER JOIN @p p2  ON p1.productionRunId = p2.productionRunId
    AND p2.startTime < p1.startTime
    GROUP BY
        p1.startTime,
        p1.productionRunId,
        p1.statusCodeId
) AS ElapsedPeriods
GROUP BY
    productionRunId,
    statusCodeId
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! That was It.

Comment: @ZackScriven - if this was the/your answer please mark it so using the gray checkbox on the left side of the answer.